# Solving a system of Linear Equations through Matrix methods

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Consider the following linear equations

$1.x+0.y=2$

$0.x+1.y=3$

$0.x+0.y=3$

Obviously the above system has $0$ solutions.

But when you solve it in a matrix form

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
3\\
3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Multiply both sides of the equation with
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
which happens to be the left inverse of the co-efficient matrix, you get $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = 3$

Please give me an explanation to contradict this approach

Answer (score 1):

Left-inverses prove injectivity, which isn't really what you are interested in here. You would need to find a right-inverse (which doesn't exist here) in order to prove the existence of a solution of a linear system for any right-hand-side.

Comment: You have found the solution of the normal equation. This is the combination of the columns of the coefficient matrix which is closest to the right hand side vector in Euclidean norm

Comment: In other words, you have found the least-squares solution here.